# Can I use the Contact Other Plane spell to get a demon's true name?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes

Can a player use the [*contact other plane*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contact-other-plane) spell to get a demon's true name?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already. It's usually best to have each post focused on one question so that the answers can be more targetted towards that question. As it stands, there are a lot of questions in this post, although some are related enough that I'd say they're part of the same question. I'd recommend splitting everything after "And another question:" into a new post. It's ok to have multiple posts asking different questions at the same time. I hope you get the answers you're after!

Comment: It is still more than one question. Whether you can contact specific or random creatures is one question. If the creature is forced to tell you the truth is a completely different question. Also, similar to your other question, could you please clarify what you didn't understand in the spell description?

Comment: I see it as two different questions for another reason: the headline asks about using the spell "to get a demon's true name" and then your main text asks about asking a demon "its true name". These are different.  In the first form, you might be asking another entity besides the demon in question, to tell you the demon's true name. I would give different answers to these two different questions, so I need to know what you really are asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes, but not easily, and it depends on your DM and your amassing the necessary preparatory knowledge

Based on the answer to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63084/how-do-you-decide-who-will-be-contacted-by-contact-other-plane-spell) it seems your DM could decide to allow you to contact a particular named entity with the *contact other plane* spell.

But since the spell description says nothing about forcing or guaranteeing a truthful answer, your best chance is to get the answer from another entity who knows a demon’s name and can be relied upon to tell it to you truthfully.

Toward this end, your DM might make you pass History, Arcana and/or Religion checks to know the name of a long-dead sage who (1) has a likelihood of possessing the requisite knowledge (of a demon’s true name) and (2) who is likely to be compliant and truthful to the questioning enabled by your casting *contact other plane* (perhaps based on their alignment and their connection to you via the plot or backstory of your adventure, e.g. were they a member of your faction 100 years ago and would sympathize with your purpose?).

Spending time on research at a relevant library might convince your DM to lower the DC for such checks.